# PHP submitting more variables in a form when I have mysql fetch assoc?

Tags: php, mysql

```
echo "<form method='post' action='proceed.php'>";
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    extract($row);

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$name}<input type='hidden' name='itemid' value='{$itemid}'></td>";
    echo "<td>&#36;{$price}</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href='remove_from_cart.php?id={$id}&name={$name}' class='btn btn-danger'>";
    echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Remove from cart";
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $total_price+=$price;
}
echo"<input type='hidden' name='itemsprice' value='{$total_price}' id='itemsprice'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>Total</b></td>";
echo "<td>&#36;{$total_price}</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<input type='submit'>";
echo "</a>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
}
```

Hello, so basically what I want to do is makeing a PHP cart/shop system, and I want to make each of the rows send a variable to the proceed.php, do I have to put the  inside the mysql fetch assoc for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an array-style name for the input:

```
echo "<td>{$name}<input type='hidden' name='itemid[]' value='{$itemid}'></td>";
```

Then in `proceed.php`, `$_POST['itemid']` will be an array containing all the inputs.